# Getting Message Unauthenticated While Sending Data to Database Table Using Laravel Authentiation and Ajax

Tags: php, laravel

I create an API using Laravel 5.8 API Authentication (Passport) saving data with postman getting generated token it works. But when I send it to ajax it gives a this message

({message: "Unauthenticated."})

My Route is

`````````
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
    Route::resource('r-camera', 'API\RearcamerasController');

});
````````

````````
My ajax code is 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('#btn-add').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   /*Ajax Request Header setup*/
   $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
  });


   $('#btn-add').html('Sending..');

   /* Submit form data using ajax*/
   $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:8000/api/r-camera",
      method: 'post',
      data: $('#frmAddTask').serialize(),
      success: function(response){
         //------------------------
            $('#btn-add').html('Submit');
            $('#res_message').show();
            $('#res_message').html(response.msg);
            $('#msg_div').removeClass('d-none');

            document.getElementById("frmAddTask").reset(); 
            setTimeout(function(){
            $('#res_message').hide();
            $('#msg_div').hide();
            },10000);
         //--------------------------
      }});
   });
});
</script>
`````````

to run API on postman use this toke and it's run

Authorization

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xr99v.png) **Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImMzZjQ5ZTA1MzdmMWQxYzI5YjBhNzQ5N2EyZjhiMDVjYjliYzAyMTQ3OWMxMWVkZjEzNDIyNjE1Y2RjNDZmNDVmZjE3MzNmMjZiN2E5MTQxIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIzIiwianRpIjoiYzNmNDllMDUzN2YxZDFjMjliMGE3NDk3YTJmOGIwNWNiOWJjMDIxNDc5YzExZWRmMTM0MjI2MTVjZGM0NmY0NWZmMTczM2YyNmI3YTkxNDEiLCJpYXQiOjE1Nzk4NDgxMjIsIm5iZiI6MTU3OTg0ODEyMiwiZXhwIjoxNjExNDcwNTIyLCJzdWIiOiIxIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.DS3-YniGiLIr3lTm08DJSd8fdITwYHqW22J9CjjoRFhGAZ4mXpCwb6U1UbJw8yKAQONC93Sj1OxUisg-QfrJ7vUUzFPMCoDDTbS-Hgu5CeRZrLFprYLzm1Eu0WLV9VRAbeQ0P8hPa5tzhbn4oVJ3KMHipjvw3UKse-Noe50LZuktIDZ0KeA1v3PhaaMTCmfXy7S0VXFMSngQbkDVQUWLt8EwcEAGeRGwpvtYz9FzhgSSF5yTz48EvpbqncgLyUo7a0TnbwPYzYR__cyXLeF6FmrrWfaEUD0pkPwZRtalF0bMXPrH-0AKmXJSPQYJxC5SySxf5a5QEVqhzwOlHPTl7iLZkVI9NWMipTmoaf5cSNI4k7gkN8yvYzHbY3C78zFSlEc9zTE9FGX9u4UIIgCEnFAIMwLI20jaUyopFkRMpo5qeU3krZQnLfHaeS5K5MnFEfNarUp4CNvGf-aITxl07KFOSjWk0s5qA9llJCYh7NpdOY2IA1Wq8XxR2qDW7ZwNFmoF83vBxKMjhGEbJokuKJNCmoO591MuOBgzJZt8SJdwn2abrQ96AEL4rJ8HC6pFlMbaHFydwlirwE3NCzIQDsRYr0CjLbvfzGQ4axdq5I-IAo-bcUh2KinuA1XqKEerCrUCNj6oaGKFOAt1VoqZBoRTyLEp8amh7YwG43v_mTE**

But when I post a request through ajax from the dashboard 
[{message: "Unauthenticated."}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVMoe.png)

Please look attached images for more clear and please help me to solve my issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: generate token and save in localstorage then from localstorage get token and add in ajax call

Comment: "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}" this one????

Comment: no this route is protect by passport auth right so you need Bearer token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to send the `Authorization` header in your ajax setup as well in your blade file.

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
          'Authorization': 'Bearer {{ $your_bearer_token }}'
      }
  });
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but now I get your_bearer_token Undefined variable can please help me to solve this issue also...How I define my bearer token ?? Is it generate always the same ???????

Comment: @ayushflitzip You have to get the bearer token and pass it to your blade. I just added `$your_bearer_token` for demonstration purpose. It doesn't exist on it's own.

Comment: @ayushflitzip To get the token, you will have to do `$token = JWTAuth::getToken();` and pass it to blade in your `compact('token')` style and your header code would look like `'Authorization': 'Bearer {{ $token }}'`

Comment: Sir, I create an API using a passport

Comment: @ayushflitzip When you send the token to front end, you should store the token in the browser like in `localStorage`.

Comment: Sir,I got this message Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '=>'  why????

Comment: $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
         
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
          'Authorization' => 'Bearer .$token',
          'Accept' => 'application/json',
      }
  });

Comment: @ayushflitzip It's not a PHP script. It's javascript. You will have to use `:` instead of `=>`

Comment: sir now I got this message... {message: "", exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException",…}

Comment: sir I pass this url  http://localhost:8000/api/r-camera ?api_token= Auth::user()->api_token

Comment: @ayushflitzip It's hard for me to debug just looking at the error messages.

Comment: and do changes in my API\controller files  $token =  auth()->user()->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;

Comment: @ayushflitzip I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @ayushflitzip Glad to help.